# SQL Server: log modifications

Tags: sql-server, logging

I have a SQL Server and I need to log any changes made to a set of tables and their fields. Information needed is the user, the date time, the related table / field and the new value.

I saw the Change Data Capture (CDC) feature which seems perfect but it requires a non-standard version - and I have (and I may only have) the standard version.

The single solution I see is to use trigger, but it may cause performance troubles (it blocks the related table while the log is being inserted). Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want triggers to do this, then define a stored procedure that will insert entries in log, after inserting the data into the table successfully.

> it blocks the related table while the log is being inserted

Most probably you are using FOR INSERT for trigger, i think you should try AFTER INSERT